# sed replace eating non-matching paterns

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to do a simple `sed` replace but I'm getting a strange result. I just want to take any of my conditions that end in .0_ and replace them with *. However, something unexpected is occurring. It's eating anything of the form "x0*". What do I need to change here?

```
$ cat test.csv
    Ar_phi_2.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_3.2_um_V_20_V,4586.516493
    Ar_phi_2.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_3.2_um_V_20.0_V,4586.516493
$ sed -i -- 's|.0_|_|g' test.csv ;
$ cat test.csv
    Ar_phi_2.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff__ns_d_3.2_um_V__V,4586.516493
    Ar_phi_2.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff__ns_d_3.2_um_V_20_V,4586.516493
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try change

```
sed -i -- 's|.0_|_|g'
```

to

```
sed -i -- 's|\.0_|_|g'
```